# Error while triggering a python script using os.system. Script takes sys.argv arguments

Tags: python-2.7

Simple script1.py that takes arguments and calls script2.py by passing them to os.system() :

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import os
import sys
os.system("script2.py sys.argv[1] sys.argv[2]")
```

Running this :

```
./script1.py "arg1" "arg2"
```

Getting this single error :

```
sh: 1: script2.py: not found
```

Both scripts are present in the same directory.
Applied chmod 777 on both script1.py and script2.py and are executable.
Both scripts call the same interpreter installed at /usr/bin/env python.

When I try these :

```
os.system("./script2.py sys.argv[1] sys.argv[2]")
os.system("python script2.py sys.argv[1] sys.argv[2]")
```

The sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2] are being considered as strings instead of dynamic variables

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with:
`./script2.py "arg1" "arg2"`
Inside the `os.system`?

**UPDATE 2**

Try with:

```
import urllib
call_with_args = "./script2.py '%s' '%s'" % (str(arg1), str(arg2))

os.system(call_with_args)
```

Comment: When I try this `./script2.py "arg1" "arg2"` and this `python script2.py "arg1" "arg2"`, the sys.argv[1] and sys.argv[2] are being considered as strings instead of dynamic variables.

Comment: ah @Avinash you might want to URL encode the args or putting quotes around it.

Comment: `call_with_args = "./script2.py %s %s" % (sys.argv[1], sys.argv[2])
os.system(call_with_args)`. used this but getting this error: `sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`. Did it work for you ? @andrea-f

Comment: @Avinash check updated answer, it depends on what you pass in the inputs.

Comment: Tried using quotes around the sys args `call_with_args = "./script2.py %s %s" % ("sys.argv[1]", "sys.argv[2]")` Now it runs but considers the sys.args as string values (string 'sys.argv[1]'). I did't get the URL encode part. Can you please elaborate ? **update** : sorry got you wrong earlier. Yes i did add quotes to the args when passing them to script1.py

Comment: Hi, that will not work as you are converting to string. URLencode is to make sure the string being passed in is URL compliant as if you were entering it in a browser.

Comment: I tried this too : `call_with_args = "./script2.py '%s' '%s'" % (urllib.urlencode(sys.argv[1]), urllib.urlencode(sys.argv[2]))
os.system(call_with_args)`  Error faced : `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./script1.py", line 9, in <module>
    call_with_args = "./script2.py '%s' '%s'" % (urllib.urlencode(sys.argv[1]), urllib.urlencode(sys.argv[2]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/urllib.py", line 1324, in urlencode
    raise TypeError
TypeError: not a valid non-string sequence or mapping object`

Comment: tried typecasting to string too - `call_with_args = "./script2.py '%s' '%s'" % (str(arg1), str(arg2))` Error : `sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string`

Comment: Can you share an example input?